# Class Leet Code - Add two Numbers - Why can't I get the value of the first recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, recursion, linked-list

Here is the class ListNode:

```
 class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next
```

and here is the solution class:

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        print(l1.next.val)
```

For the case where L1 is = ListNode(2, ListNode(4, ListNode(3))),why do I get the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
print(l1.next.val)

I was thinking about getting 4. But the output seems to give me 4 plus the error...

I was thinking about getting 4. But the output seems to give me 4 plus the error...

Comment: what is the second argument which you pass to `addTwoNumbers`?

Comment: What numbers are you trying to add?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre] and make sure that someone else can **copy and paste** the code in the question, **without changing or adding anything**, and **directly** see the **exact** problem. Show a corresponding [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by **copying and pasting, starting from the line that says** `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: I see that the question is tagged [tag:recursion], but I don't see any attempt to use recursion in the code here.

Comment: We aren't told how this function is used, so it's hard to answer your question, but that function doesn't match the type hints you gave for it. Well technically it does but it really doesn't.